# tkinter calculate multiple entry widgets

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm fairly new to tkinter and building a calculator that will calculate the amounts entered by the user and give a total printed to a label field called *Total*. That's the first issue. My code for it:

```
                entries_list = []
                for number in range(0, 66):
                    entries_list += [Entry(root, width=10)]


                def mod_calculation():
                       for entries in entries_list:
                           output = (entries.get())
                           answer = 0
                           answer += int(output)
                           print(answer)
```

The second issue is: I'm using a loop to create all the labels and entry fields (thanks to a post I saw here for some sample code). It works perfect for the labels, but only creates on column of entry fields. There are 70 fields in total.

My code:

```
                  labels_list = Label(root, text="Item1", padx=40, pady=20), Label(root, 
                  text="Item2", padx=40, pady=20), \
                  Label(root, text="Item3", padx=40, pady=20), Label(root, text="Item4", 
                  padx=40, pady=20) 

                  current_row = 1
                  current_column = 1
                  current_column2 = 2

                  for labels in labels_list:
                     labels.grid(row=current_row, column=current_column)
                     current_row += 1
                     if current_row >= 11:
                        current_column += 2
                        current_row = 1
                  for entries in entries_list:
                      entries.grid(row=current_row, column=current_column2)
                      current_row += 1
                      if current_row >= 11:
                         current_column += 2
                         current_row = 1
```

Screenshot of the outcome:

[image]

If I use 1 loop for 2nd issue, this happens:

```
for labels in labels_list:
labels.grid(row=current_row, column=current_column)
current_row += 1
if current_row >= 22:
    current_column += 1
    current_row = 1
entries = Entry(root)
entries.grid(row=current_row, column=current_column)
current_column = 2
current_row += 1
if current_row >= 22:
    current_column += 1
    current_row = 1
```

[image]

Just an update, 2nd issue resolved thanks to acw1668.

Still struggling with first issue, used acw1668's advise and got an new issue:  The empty fields (not filled in by user) is returning ' ' and causing the error:

```
def mod_calculation():
    try:
        answer = 0  # initialize answer
        for entries in entries_list:
            output = entries.get()
            answer += int(output)
        print(answer)
    except ValueError as ex:
        print(ex)
```

This works to bypass the *invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''*  issue, but calculating each number separately:

```
def mod_calculation():
    try:
        answer = 0
        for entries in entries_list:
            output = entries.get()
            for i in output:
                answer += int(i)
        print(answer)
    except ValueError as x:
        print(x)
```

eg. If I enter in entry box 1 "12" and Entry Box 2 "12 the answer isn't 24, but 6 (1+2+1+2) not (12 +12)

Any help much appreciated guys.

Comment: You have a paragraph that starts with "the second issue" but you never said what the first issue is. What's the first issue?

Comment: I think first issue is that `answer` is reset to zero in each iteration of for loop. For second issue, wrong column variable is updated in the for loop of entries. However, why don't you use one for loop for both label and entry together?

Comment: Bryan Oakley
The first issue is, I have to calculate all the entry fields in the picture and get a total amount. When I use get to pull the fields, I get a integer issue, as it's pulling a tkinter object as a string, simply int(str.get) don't work.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is due to that `answer` is reset to zero in each iteration of the for loop. `answer` should be initialized to zero before the for loop instead:

```py
def mod_calculation():
    try:
        answer = 0  # initialize answer
        for entries in entries_list:
            output = entries.get().strip()
            if output:
                answer += int(output)
        print(answer)
    except ValueError as ex:
        print(ex)
```

For second issue, wrong column variable `current_column` is used instead of the correct variable `current_column2`:

```py
for entries in entries_list:
    entries.grid(row=current_row, column=current_column2)
    current_row += 1
    if current_row >= 11:
        current_column2 += 2  # used current_column2 instead of current_column
        current_row = 1
```

Suggest to combine the two for loops into one:

```py
for i, (label, entry) in enumerate(zip(labels_list, entries_list)):
    col, row = divmod(i, 10)
    label.grid(row=row, column=col*2)
    entry.grid(row=row, column=col*2+1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, 2nd part is working as intended, however I still get this error on calculation part:  < invalid literal for int() with base 10: >.

Comment: It means that one of the entries has an input `>`.

Comment: Thanks, your print(ex) pointed out the problem, the empty fields (not filled in by user) is returning ' ' and causing the error, I have tried work arounds, but how do I ignore the empty fields when calculating? This is not working:  if Entry.get()== ''
   Entry.insert(0, END)

Comment: @DirkleRoux Answer updated to skip empty inputs inside `mod_calculation()`.